# Laravel redirect to another page 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel

I have a users table , and have data and this data if clicked its redirect to another page , this page is data from users->id .and its my Controller:

```
 public function indexDataTables_nonpns()
{

    $users = User::with('master_agama','master_unit_kerja')->whereNotIn('roles_id',['2','3'])->get();


    return Datatables::of($users)->addIndexColumn()
    ->addColumn('Nama', function ($users) {
        return '<a href="/project/non_pns/'.$users->id.'" target="_blank" >'.$users->nama.'</a>';
    })

    ->rawColumns(['Nama' => 'Nama'])
    ->make(true);

}
```

this data will redirect to

```
**return '<#a href="/project/non_pns/'.$users->id.'" target="_blank" >'.$users->nama.'</a>';**
```

and its controller to showing page :

```
 public function show($id) 
{

    $users = User::findOrFail($id);
    if (!$users)
    abort(404);
    $keluarga =   Data_Keluarga::where('user_id',$id)->get();
    $pendidikan = Data_riwayat_pendidikan::where('user_id',$id)->get();
    $pelatihan = Master_seminar_pelatihan::where('user_id',$id)->get();

   //dd($pelatihan);
     return view('admin.profile', ['users' => $users ,'keluarga'=> $keluarga,'pendidikan'=> $pendidikan
     ,'pelatihan' => $pelatihan
     ]);
}
```

and its this route :

```
Route::get('project/non_pns/{id}', 'AdminController@show')->name('show');
Route::get('/profile', 'AdminController@profile')->name('profiles');
```

but this if clicked this button , its **401
Unauthorized , You Dont Have Access For This Page**

i dont know , i just cleared/delete all data in database , and its make this route get error . please help

Comment: Can you post routes.php whole file code?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your function use bellow code

```
public function insert(){


//your code

return redirect('store');
}
```

if you want to pass id in redirect

```
public function insert(){


$id=2;


return redirect('store/'.$id);
}
```